# Android Calendar: Changing the start day of week

Tags: java, android, calendar

i have a little problem, i'm developing an application, and i need to change the start day of the week from monday to another one (thursday, of saturday). is this possible in android,
 i need to calculate the start to week and its end knowing the date. (the week starts ano thursday as example)

Note: i'm just a beginner in android development.
here is my code
SimpleDateFormat dateformate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM");

```
// get today and clear time of day
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

// get start of this week in milliseconds
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, cal.getFirstDayOfWeek());
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 7*(WeekIndex-1));
result = dateformate.format(cal.getTime());

cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 6 );

result=result+" - " + dateformate.format(cal.getTime());
```

using the above code im getting the result but with monday as the star of week.

Note: i can't add day to the result because week index changes with the changing of it's start

Comment: "i need to change the start day of the week" -- in *what*? `CalendarView`? Something else?

Comment: check my post now, and sorry for may bad english

Comment: For questions that pertain to Java, not Android, please use the `java` tag.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Calendar days have values 1-7 for days Sunday-Saturday. `getFirstDayOfWeek` returns one of this values (usually of Monday or Sunday) depending on used `Locale`. `Calendar.getInstance` uses default `Locale` depening on phone's settings, which in your case has Monday as first day of the week.

One solution would be to use other `Locale`:

```
Calendar.getInstance(Locale.US).getFirstDayOfWeek()
```

would return `1`, which is value of `Calendar.SUNDAY`

Other solution would be to use chosen day of week value like

```
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.FRIDAY);
```

Problem is, `Calendar` is using its inner first day of the week value in `set` as well. Example:

```
Calendar mondayFirst = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.GERMANY); //Locale that has Monday as first day of week
mondayFirst.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SUNDAY);
log(DateUtils.formatDateTime(context, mondayFirst.getTimeInMillis(), 0));
//prints "May 19" when runned on May 13

Calendar sundayFirst = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.US); //Locale that has Sunday as first day of week
sundayFirst.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SUNDAY);
log(DateUtils.formatDateTime(context, sundayFirst.getTimeInMillis(), 0));
//prints "May 12" when runned on May 13
```

If you don't want to use `Locale` or you need other day as the first day of the week, it may be best to calculate start of the week on your own.

Answer (score 4):

```
GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(yy, currentMonth, 0);
```

changing the value 0 - starts day from monday
changing the value 1 - starts day from sunday
and so on..

hope this helps and works :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    public int getWeekdayOfMonth(int year, int month){
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(year, month-1, 1);
    dayOfWeek = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)-1;
    return dayOfWeek;
}
```

weekday  = getWeekdayOfMonth();

```
int day = (weekday - firstweek) < 0 ? (7 - (firstweek - weekday)) : (weekday - firstweek);
```

"firstweek" means what the start day of you want

then you can calculate the first day  you should show.If you have simple method,please tell us. thks

Answer (score 0):

Problem in my case was using Calendar instance returned by `MaterialDialog` `DatePicker`, which although having the same `Locale` as my `Calendar.getInstance(Locale...)`, was having different `Calendar.firstDayOfWeek`. If you're experiencing the same issue, my workaround was to create new instance of `Calendar` with my Locale and just changing the property `time` to the one returned by the `DatePicker` as following:

```
val correctCal = Calendar.getInstance(Locale...)?.apply {
        time = datePickerCal.time
}
```

This should return proper `Calendar.firstDayOfWeek` based on your `Locale`.