# Hours duration calculation issue using two Date objects

Tags: java, date, dst, date-difference

I have a method in my class to calculate the hourly duration of two dates.

```
public static double getDuration(Date startDate, Date endDate){
    return (endDate.getTime()-startDate.getTime()) / (1000.0 * 60 * 60);
}
```

My input dates are `28-10-2017 14:00` and `29-10-2017 02:00`. During Daylight Saving periods duration gives `13.0` which is wrong.

If I write a simple program with this input I am getting correct result. So just checked the `Date` object. In my application input it comes as dayofWeek as 7 for start date and 1 for end date. But my simple program gives it as 1 for start date and 2 for end date. Any idea how this is happening?

Comment: How do you build your input dates ?

Comment: It already has been done for you. See the [Java Time Trail](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/period.html)

Comment: "During day light saving periods duration gives 13.0 which is wrong." No it's not. Not if there was a DST transition between that 2pm and the 2am - there could easily have been 13 elapsed hours (or 11).

Comment: For the love of all things good, do not try to calculate date differences like this. There is just so much insanity surrounding dates, times and timezones that the fabric of spacetime could not cope with another "there are always 24 hours in a day" assumption. See https://github.com/kdeldycke/awesome-falsehood#dates-and-time

Comment: @M.leRutte I am using java 7. The tutorial which you shared is Java8

Comment: @StéphaneAmmar This is there in the screen already fetched from the database table.

Comment: If you are on JSE7 then http://www.joda.org/joda-time/

Comment: Why would you use Java 7? Java 7 is from 2011, Java 8 from 2014. You should be on Java 9 by now.

Comment: @JonSkeet I didn't get your calculation. Could you please explain ?

Comment: @M.leRutte Certain things clients decides not us :-)

Comment: @ptomli I cannot use any 3rd party packages other than spring and hibernate.

Comment: What's the values of `endDate.getTime()` and `startDate.getTime()`? And what's the JVM default timezone (`TimeZone.getDefault().getID()`)?

Comment: Suppose there's a "fall back" from 2017-10-29T01:30 to 2017-10-29T00:30 as a DST transition. That means that the hour between 00:30 and 01:30 happens twice. That means the *elapsed* time between 2017-10-28T14:00 and 2017-10-29T02:00 is 13 hours. If you convert each local time into UTC, you should see that clearly. The reverse happens if 00:30 to 01:30 is skipped due to a "spring forward".

Comment: FYI, you are using one of the troublesome old date-time classes that is now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes. In particular, `Date` is replaced by `Instant`.

Comment: @Hugo Default Time zone is "Europe/Berlin"

Comment: And the values of endDate.getTime() and startDate.getTime()?

Comment: @JAVA_CAT Check the locale in effect for your application and test. For example, en_US week starts Sunday, en_GB week starts Monday. This suggests inconsistent environments between application and test. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/28021267/134894

Comment: @Hugo end date = 1509238800000 , start date = 1509192000000

Comment: @ptomli Locale is en_US in application , what you meant by test?

Comment: @JAVA_CAT So the difference is really 13 hours (I explain in details in my answer below) - and the day of week is irrelevant to this result, btw (it's a different issue, probably caused by the locale, as already said - maybe you could post a different question specifically to address this issue, adding the code you're using to get the day of week and so on - but remember to make a search before asking, I'm sure this was already covered before).

Comment: @Hugo Thanks. But to solve this I think I need to work on Locale Issue. I will add another post. Thanks.

Comment: @JAVA_CAT The 13-hour difference is due to timezone (actually, it depends on what's in database and/or how you're retrieving the date from it - maybe this code could be relevant). The locale controls another aspects (like the beginning of the week and other stuff), but it has no relation to the timezones (thus, it's not related to the difference between the dates)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## tl;dr

For Java 6 and Java 7, use the *ThreeTen-Backport* project.

### 12 hours

Between 2 PM and 2 AM in [`Europe/Berlin`](https://time.is/Berlin) time zone on those dates is twelve hours.

```
org.threeten.bp.temporal.ChronoUnit.HOURS.between( 

    org.threeten.bp.LocalDateTime
        .parse( "2017-10-28T14:00:00" )
        .atZone( org.threeten.bp.ZoneId.of( "Europe/Berlin" ) ) ,  // Producing a `ZonedDateTime` instance. 

    org.threeten.bp.LocalDateTime
        .parse( "2017-10-29T02:00:00" )
        .atZone( org.threeten.bp.ZoneId.of( "Europe/Berlin" ) )  // Producing another `ZonedDateTime` instance. 

)
```

> 12

## 13 hours

To see the effect of a [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) cutover scheduled for 3 AM in Berlin time, change your start-stop to 3 PM and 3 AM, to get 13 hours rather than 12 hours.

The hour of 02:00-03:00 repeats, as discussed in the [Answer by Hugo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46773852/642706).

```
org.threeten.bp.temporal.ChronoUnit.HOURS.between( 

    org.threeten.bp.LocalDateTime
        .parse( "2017-10-28T15:00:00" )
        .atZone( org.threeten.bp.ZoneId.of( "Europe/Berlin" ) ) ,  // Producing a `ZonedDateTime` instance. 

    org.threeten.bp.LocalDateTime
        .parse( "2017-10-29T03:00:00" )
        .atZone( org.threeten.bp.ZoneId.of( "Europe/Berlin" ) )  // Producing another `ZonedDateTime` instance. 

)
```

> 13

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://www.ideone.com/hCH76T), using the java.time classes built into Java 8.

## java.time

This has been covered many many times already on Stack Overflow, so search for more info.

Briefly…

Avoid the `Date` class. Use only the java.time classes. Likewise, avoid the Joda-Time project for new work as the team advises migration to java.time classes.

Parse your input strings as `LocalDateTime` values because they lack an indicator of time zone or offset-from-UTC. A `LocalDateTime` does *not* represent an actual moment on the timeline, but we'll get there; read on.

Tip: write your date-time strings in standard ISO 8601 format, used by default in java.time classes when parsing/generating strings.

Define a time zone (`ZoneId`) intended for these values. Specify a zone by proper name in `continent/region` format such as `Africa/Casablanca` or `Europe/Berlin`. Never use 3-4 pseudo zone names such as `PST` or `CST`.

Apply the zone to produce a `ZonedDateTime` object for each moment.

Calculate elapsed time instantiating a `Duration` object, or by calling `ChronoUnit.HOURS.between`.

Much of java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [*ThreeTen-Backport*](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. The java.time classes are built into Java 8 and Java 9.

---

[image: Table of all date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy]

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later
- Built-in.
- Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
- Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)
- Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))
- The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
- See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Comment: Somewhere in the comments on the question there's a note that it's JSE7, so no `java.time`

Comment: @ptomli (A) It is the responsibility of that author to edit important facts into the Question rather than bury in comments. (B) Much of java.time is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in the ThreeTen-Backport project.

Answer (score 2):

## DST cut-over at 03:00

You said [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46772268/hours-duration-calculation-issue-using-two-date-objects#comment80492723_46772268) your [JVM default timezone](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html#systemDefault--) is [`Europe/Berlin`](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/germany/berlin?year=2017). In October **28<sup>th</sup>** 2017, Berlin is in [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time), so the offset is `+02:00` (two hours ahead of [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time)). When the local time gets to October **29<sup>th</sup>** 2017 at **3 AM**, the clocks shift back 1 hour, to 2 AM (and offset changes from `+02:00` to `+01:00`).

This means that, in this timezone, all local times between 2 AM and 2:59 AM exist **twice** (in offsets `+02:00` and `+01:00`). Just to better illustrate it, that's how the timeline would be in this timezone, hour by hour:

- `2017-10-29T01:00+02:00` (1 AM in DST - offset `+02:00`)
- `2017-10-29T02:00+02:00` (1 hour later, **2 AM** in DST - offset `+02:00`)
- `2017-10-29T02:00+01:00` (1 hour later, **2 AM** *not* in DST - offset `+01:00`)
- `2017-10-29T03:00+01:00` (1 hour later, 3 AM *not* in DST - offset `+01:00`)

Your [`Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) object with its [`getTime()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime--) value equal to `1509238800000` corresponds to the **second** 2 AM (the *not-in-DST* date), then the difference will be 13 hours.

---

This can become more clear if we convert the timestamps to [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) (using the [values provided in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46772268/hours-duration-calculation-issue-using-two-date-objects#comment80493766_46772268)):

```
Timestamp (getTime()) | Europe/Berlin timezone              | UTC
----------------------|-------------------------------------|------------------
1509192000000         | 2017-10-28T14:00+02:00 (in DST)     | 2017-10-28T12:00Z
1509238800000         | 2017-10-29T02:00+01:00 (not in DST) | 2017-10-29T01:00Z
```

Note that, when converting to UTC, it becomes clear that the difference is really 13 hours.

Comment: @BasilBourque I double checked. In Europe/Berlin timezone, at October 29th 2017, the wall-clock [repeats the 02:00-03:00 hour](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/germany/berlin?year=2017). Check this: https://ideone.com/ATOofe

Comment: I was wrong: 2 AM vs 3 AM cut-over. Deleted my comment. I assumed a 2 AM cut-over as used in US/Canada. Then I learned [`Europe/Berlin`](https://time.is/Berlin) uses a 3 AM cut-over. I'll leave this comment for any other too-quick-to-assume Americans/Canadians.

Answer (score 1):

First off, [read this](https://github.com/kdeldycke/awesome-falsehood#dates-and-time), cry a little, and then be glad you're not required to write date/time libraries, because others have done it for you

Then add [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) to your project.

If you **know** the timezone of all the dates in your database then you should be able to use [Duration](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/key_duration.html), [Period](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/key_period.html) or [Interval](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/key_interval.html), depending on your needs.

Comment: I cannot suggest a new package as this is not allowed.

Comment: Although a great API (I used a lot and really love it), Joda-Time is now in maintainance mode and being replaced by the new APIs, so I don't recommend start a new project with it. Even in [joda's website](http://www.joda.org/joda-time) it says: **"Note that Joda-Time is considered to be a largely “finished” project. No major enhancements are planned. If using Java SE 8, please migrate to java.time (JSR-310)."**. In Java 7, there's the [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp), a great backport for Java 8's new date/time classes.

Comment: @Hugo could you please tell me what is wrong with my code shown above? and how dayofweek affects duration result?

Comment: @JAVA_CAT To me it's not clear how the day of week should affect the results. Maybe if you edit your question and add more code and provide more context to it... My guess is that the day of week is not relevant, though

Comment: @Hugo "finished" != "obsolete". I would argue that using a well tested library like Joda-Time would be preferential to a newer library like the 310 backport, if for no other reason than proven quality. The same page also says **Joda-Time is the de facto standard date and time library for Java prior to Java SE 8.**

Comment: Well, the backport was made by the same authors of Java 8 API (btw, the same author of Joda-Time) who made [some improvements in the new API](http://blog.joda.org/2009/11/why-jsr-310-isn-joda-time_4941.html). I just think that using the backport make a future migration to Java 8 easier, as it'll require just a change in the imports and a few adjustments, while migrating from Joda would be more difficult as the API's are similar [but not exactly the same](http://blog.joda.org/2014/11/converting-from-joda-time-to-javatime.html).

Comment: And IMO, when the authors of both API's recommend migrating to the newer one, to me it's enough (but I can understand your point). But I'm not saying that you're wrong, Joda-Time is still a great API. Anyway, I didn't say it's obsolete (although I can see how you inferred that), nor did I say your answer is wrong. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: @Hugo NP. Date/Time/Timezones are complex, even in the meta ;-)

Answer (score 1):

First of all I would suggest to use a library that handle different time zones and changes on times (like summer +1 hours and so on). For this I suggest JodaTime.

```
 Hours hoursDiff =  Hours.hoursBetween(start.toLocalDate(), end.toLocalDate()).getDays())
```

and then you can do

```
hoursDiff.getHours(); //returns and int
```

You can convert date to datetime (required in the params) like this:

```
Date date = new Date();
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(date);

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/joda-time/joda-time -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
    <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.7</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: The Joda-Time project is now in maintenance mode. The team advises migration to the java.time classes.